# what can be used in place of window.location.replace to avoid page reloading?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using product filtering in a site like Flipkart. And I do not want to reload the page after filtering data. This is my jquery code for filtering data. Filter class is used in all the filters. Give some suggestions plz.

```
$('.filter').click(function() {    

    var typef = '';    
    var currentURL = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;    
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("search") > -1) {
        var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var aquery = searchParams.get('query');    
        typef = 'search';    
    }    
    var brands = [];    
    var colors = [];    
    var price = [];    
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {    
        $("input:checkbox[name=brand_check]:checked").each(function() {    
            brands.push($(this).val());    
        });    
        $("input:checkbox[name=color_check]:checked").each(function() {    
            colors.push($(this).val());    
        });    
        $("input:radio[name=price_check]:checked").each(function() {    
            price.push($(this).val());    
        });    
        var filterdata = {    
            brands: jQuery.unique(brands),    
            color: jQuery.unique(colors),    
            price: jQuery.unique(price)    
        };    
        var filteruri = jQuery.param(filterdata);    
        if (typef == 'search' && typeof aquery !== "undefined" && aquery !== '') {    
            window.location.replace(currentURL + '?query=' + encodeURIComponent(aquery) + '&f=' + encodeURIComponent(filteruri));    
        } else {    
            window.location.replace(currentURL + '?f=' + encodeURIComponent(filteruri));    
        }    
    } else {     
        $('input:checkbox[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('checked', false);    
        $("input:checkbox[name=brand_check]:checked").each(function() {
            brands.push($(this).val());    
        });    
        $("input:checkbox[name=color_check]:checked").each(function() {
            colors.push($(this).val());    
        });    
        $("input:radio[name=price_check]:checked").each(function() {
            price.push($(this).val());    
        });    
        var filterdata = {    
            brands: jQuery.unique(brands),    
            color: jQuery.unique(colors),    
            price: jQuery.unique(price)    
        };    
        var filteruri = jQuery.param(filterdata);    
        if (typef == 'search' && typeof aquery !== "undefined" && aquery !== '') {    
            if (filteruri.length > 0) {    
                window.location.replace(currentURL + '?query=' + encodeURIComponent(aquery) + '&f=' + encodeURIComponent(filteruri));    
            } else {    
                window.location.replace(currentURL + '?query=' + encodeURIComponent(aquery));        
            }        
        } else {    
            if (filteruri.length > 0) {    
                window.location.replace(currentURL + '?f=' + encodeURIComponent(filteruri));    
            } else {    
                window.location.replace(currentURL);    
            }    
        }    
    }    

});
```

Comment: If you don't want to refresh the page but you want to retrieve external data then welcome to the world of AJAX my friend. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_ajax.htm

Comment: But for that I have to change the whole functionality @mark

Comment: It looks like this code doesn’t do the actual filtering itself, but only prepares the URL parameters, the actual filtering seems to happen on the server side. So if you do not want this “page reload” - which is what makes your filter _work_ here in the first place - then you will have to rewrite this to use AJAX. (Or you would have to create a fully different script that handles the filtering of the data on the client side.)

Comment: can u plz suggest any code for this. I have tried but don't get results.

Comment: what you are asking of @04FS is complete overhaul of your current code (i.e. code writing) which is outside the scope of stack. your page refreshes because it is designed to, if you want it to do this on-the-fly you'll have to use ajax. there are plenty of examples online of ajax usage. i suggest you start converting your code and come back when you have some concrete questions on that. if you are working with tables (which I can't tell from this code) you can use jquery datatables.

Comment: please note: most sites I've seen will *reload* the page because it allows for better search engine indexing of specific categories .etc. while they may not use query strings they'll have something like `/products/categories/pens/red`. so you might even consider leaving it the way it is (reloading on filter) and just changing the url structure which is easy to do it codeigniter. if you choose to go this route, for ux I would suggest not filtering as the user checks boxes, but filtering after the user hits a button called `filter` which then aggregates their choices in to the url.

Comment: Now I m using ajax like this   $.ajax({
url: url
}).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
  $('body').html(data); // display data
});

Comment: it display result one time. But for next time, it does not remain dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to change url without page reloading.
Read some about manipulating browser history (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), in particular: pushState.

In your case you can use **window.history.pushState** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method).

Instead **window.location.replace** you can write something like this one:

```
window.history.pushState({ page: filteruri }, 'Page title', currentURL + '?somethingnew');
```

Comment: still it is reloading page